# Build succeeded with projects Ctrl + Shift + B that MSBuild can't build

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild

Does anyone know where I can take a look at my project if after I make a build with MSBuild through MSBuild console I get this warning:

> MSB4078: The project file 'MyProject.csproj' is not supported by
>   MSBuild and cannot be built?

My project is running with Target Framework .Net Core 2.0. The MSBuild version I am using is 14.0.25420.1

[image]

This is the cs.proj

[image]

Comment: What version of MSBuild are you running?  What format is the .csproj file?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 msbuild version is 14.0.25420.1

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the csproj file?

Comment: @SwDevMan81 question updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check what version of MSBuild are you running. I tested with the version 15.0, it runs without any error.

Generally, make sure that you have configured a build agent for your team project, and that you have **Visual Studio 2017 installed** on the agent machine and that you **installed the latest Visual Studio update**.

Also make sure you have select the MSbuild version 15.0 for the build.

See [Build your ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-core?tabs=gitvsts%2Cweb%2Cdeploy-windows) for details.

Reference this related thread： [Support for .NET Core .csproj files](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3311)

Comment: msbuild version is 14.0.25420.1

Comment: @Zinov Just try to use Msbuild 15.0 as I mentioned above, then try it again.

Answer (score 13):

You are using the new csproj file format (see `Project sdk=...`)

You will need to use MSBuild 15 in order for it to build.  You have two options:

1) Download [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and install.  Then the path will be:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

2) If you have VS installed, the path will be:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<VS Version>\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

Using MSBuild 15 should fix the error.

Comment: So much more informative than the accepted answer from the MSFT guy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use MSBuild in more reliable way.

1. Download [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15) from [Visual Studio Downloads page](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/), it includes latest MSBuild 15.* ([direct link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/3/7/C37763CB-E533-4290-BE34-1DF89C218CFE/vs_BuildTools.exe)).

   Command-line arguments documented here: [Use command-line parameters to install 
   Visual Studio 2017](http://Use%20command-line%20parameters%20to%20install%20Visual%20Studio%202017).

   All workloads and components are listed here: [Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools).
2. Use PowerShell module `VSSetup` to find MSBuild. Download it or install from here: [Github: Microsoft/Visual Studio Setup PowerShell Module](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell)

**Find MS Build**

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\VSSetup\VSSetup.psd1

$msBuildPath = (Get-VSSetupInstance | Select-VSSetupInstance -Version 15.0 -Product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools).InstallationPath

if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 8)
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64'
}
else
{
    $global:msbuildPath = Join-Path $msBuildPath 'MSBuild\15.0\Bin'
}

Write-Output "Using MSBuild from $global:msbuildPath"
Write-Output "MSBuild /version"

$msbuild = Join-Path $global:msbuildPath msbuild

& $msbuild /version
```